# Keyboard Notification

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, uikeyboard, custom-keyboard

I am trying to get a keyboard size from `userInfo` using keyboard extension.

I add

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
```

inside my *KeyboardViewController.swift* but `keyboardWillShow` never gets called.

Answer (score 8):

First register for keyboard notifications

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

    let notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    notificationCenter.removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    notificationCenter.removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}
```

then

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardHeight = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue().height
}
```

and you have your height value as a CGFloat

Answer (score 0):

In viewWillAppear, have you added `self.subscribeToKeyboardNotifications()` ? Just a guess, is your KeyboardViewController seperate from the ViewController in which the keyboard shows up? If so, have  `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil) in a func in the actual ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

use following code for **Swift 3.0**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(SignUpViewController.keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(SignUpViewController.keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

    let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
    notificationCenter.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    notificationCenter.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardHeight = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue.height

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {

        self.constraintBottomBtnNext.constant = keyboardHeight;
    }
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded();

    print(keyboardHeight);
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {

        self.constraintBottomBtnNext.constant = 0;
    }

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded();
}
```